# Submit content of div in database on button click

Tags: php, html, css, angularjs, content-management-system

I have a WYSIWYG tool where I can create a content. At the bottom, I have a form where I can submit a value (from an input text) to a database. That works fine. Now, I am trying to submit the content that has been created in the WYSIWYG in the database.

I am thinking of using a value in the input as shown below:

```
<input name="videoLink" type="text"  value="John" required/>
```

and use javascript to make the value dynamic. But there must be an easier way. To make the form submit the content of a div instead of having to type anything in the input box.

My code is shown below:

```js
angular.module("textAngularTest", ['textAngular']);

function wysiwygeditor($scope) {
  $scope.orightml = '<h2>Put Your Text Here</h2>';
  $scope.htmlcontent = $scope.orightml;
  $scope.disabled = false;
};
```

```css
.ta-editor {
  min-height: 80px;
  height: auto;
  overflow: auto;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.4/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textAngular/1.1.2/textAngular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div ng-app="textAngularTest" ng-controller="wysiwygeditor" class="container app">
  <h3>WYSIWYG Editor</h3>
  <div text-angular="text-angular" name="htmlcontent" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-disabled='disabled'></div>
  <!--<h3>Raw HTML in a text area</h3>
    <textarea ng-model="htmlcontent" style="width: 100%"></textarea>-->
  <h3>Preview</h3>
  <div ng-bind-html="htmlcontent"></div>
  <!--<h3>Bound with ta-bind, our internal html-binding directive</h3>
    <div ta-bind="text" ng-model="htmlcontent" ta-readonly='disabled'></div>-->
  <button type="button" ng-click="htmlcontent = orightml">Reset</button>

  <form action="Insert.php" method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <label><input name="videoLink" type="text" required/></label>
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="log">
  </form>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `placeholder` instead of `value`. 
Set value =" " but the `placeholder="Put text here"` ... otherwise you could get a lot of Johns.. I presume that's what you want to avoid? I don't think you can avoid php/ passing values to php from html [using javascript] to enter values into a database.

Your form isn't that big. You don't need that amount of js unless your site is using angular/is included in all pages of the CMS. So if the question is really ***how to pass variables to php with minimal javascript***, then comment.

You should still use placeholder instead of value. Otherwise if people don't change the text / maybe just press enter/submit.. your `required` error message won't fire. That's a lot of Johns in the db! :)

Hope this helps

Comment: yay! happy i could help :)